# adding multiple items to this batch script so kinda like if "a" or "b" go here

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch code that tell if its a assigned drive letter and if its cd
then checks if its ntfs, but i need to check for ntfs and fat in the same line

```
@echo off
title Test

:S1
CLS
IF EXIST Y:\ (GOTO S1B) ELSE (GOTO S2)

:S1B
CLS
wmic logicaldisk where caption="Y:" get description|find "CD">nul && goto S2 || goto    S1C

:S1C
CLS
wmic logicaldisk where caption="Y:" get filesystem|find "NTFS">nul && echo goto A || goto S2

:A
CLS
echo A
pause

:S2
CLS
echo S2 - aka failed a check
pause
```

so basically this checks if it exist then if its a cd, then does final check if its a ntfs
but i need it to check if its ntfs or fat both and if its either goto A otherwise if its say blank goto other option S2

Comment: like in LUA you could do find "NTFS","FAT" or something like find "NTFS" or "FAT" how can i do that in batch

Comment: A cdrom doesn't use NTFS or FAT - it uses a cdrom file system.

Comment: i know cd thats why i have this: wmic logicaldisk where caption="Y:" get description|find "CD">nul && goto S2 || goto    S1C just trying to find out how to check for ntfs and fat at same time

Answer (score 1):

use `findstr` instead of `find`. You can give it several strings and it returns a line, if any of the string is matched:

```
wmic logicaldisk  get /value|findstr /R "NTFS FAT"
```

To find `FAT` as well as `FAT32` and `NTFS` use `"NTFS FAT"`

to find `FAT32` and `NTFS`, but not `FAT` use `"NTFS FAT32"`

To find `FAT` and `NTFS`, but not `FAT32` use `"NTFS FAT$"`

`FAT$` will find `FAT` at the end of the line, so `FAT32` would not be reported (if you need that)

Comment: wmic logicaldisk  where caption="W:" get /value|findstr /R "NTFS FAT">nul && echo its ntfs/fat/fat32 || echo its not

Comment: i just need it to check for fat or ntfs because that would make it active, and if its not active it wouldnt have a filesystem